# Write the $u,v$ function in $z$ form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Write the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-2x-y^2+1}{(x-1)^2+y^2}+i\frac{2(x-1)y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$
>
> In the form of $z=x+iy$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-2x-y^2+1}{(x-1)^2+y^2}+i\frac{2(x-1)y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)^2-y^2+2(x-1)yi}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{((x-1)^2+yi)^2}{|(x-1)+yi|}$$

Now $$z=x+yi$$ in the denominator I can write $$|(x-1)+yi|=|z-1|=(z-1)\overline{(z-1)}$$

How can I deduce that the numerator is $(z-1)^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in last calculation :
$$f(x,y)=\frac{((x-1)+iy)^2}{\left|(x-1)+iy\right|^2} = \frac{(z-1)^2}{\left|z-1\right|^2} = \left(\frac{z-1}{\left|z-1\right|}\right)^2$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write $x^2$ in the original function. edited